# Maya/Python: How do I scale multiple selected animation curves each from their own specific pivot point?

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I'm trying to do a scale operation of multiple animation curves, each using its lowest key as the pivot point. I am thinking it should be a nested for loop structure but have not been able to get it working properly.

The scaling is simple, just:

```
mykeys = pm.keyframe( query=True, valueChange=True, absolute=True )
low = min(mykeys)
pm.scaleKey( valuePivot=low, valueScale=1.5 )
```

I am thinking it should be something similar to?

```
selectedCurves = pm.listConnections( t="animCurve")
for curve in selectedCurves:
    mykeys = pm.keyframe( query=True, valueChange=True, absolute=True )
    low = min(mykeys)
    pm.scaleKey( valuePivot=low, valueScale=1.5 )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it right, you're just not telling the command to work on only one curve at a time:

```
selectedCurves = cmds.listConnections( t="animCurve")
for curve in selectedCurves:
    mykeys = cmds.keyframe(curve, query=True, valueChange=True, absolute=True )
    low = min(mykeys)
    cmds.scaleKey(curve, valuePivot=low, valueScale=1.5 )
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple like that but couldn't find it. Works perfectly now.